# Where can I find other, similar javascript libraries, frameworks, or engines?

Tags: javascript

I recently came across [**spin.js**](http://fgnass.github.com/spin.js/). And I just realized how much can be done with javascript. It left me wondering about other awesome javascript frameworks out there that I may not know of. I wanted to created a list here for others to consult. And hopefully to learn about a few new interesting javascript projects myself, too.

- [**jQuery**](http://api.jquery.com/)
- [**jQuery.UI**](http://jqueryui.com/)
- [**YUI**](http://developer.yahoo.com/yui/)
- [**node.js**](http://nodejs.org/)
- [**spin.js**](http://fgnass.github.com/spin.js/)
- [**less.js**](http://lesscss.org/)
- [**uglify.js**](https://github.com/mishoo/UglifyJS/)
- [**sizzle.js**](http://sizzlejs.com/)

I'm more interested in specific-application libraries like spin, node or less than actual frameworks like jQuery, YUI or Dojo, etc.

Comment: Where can I find similar javascript libraries?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Spin isn't a library, it's just a cool thing. A javascript library is a handful of tools which interface with eachother and sit on top of the core JavaScript.

Node.js isn't a library either. It's a server-side JS engine which sits on V8.

YUI just sucks.

JQuery is the most community-supported and widely used. It's constantly improving and it has a minimalist syntax which is very appealing to many developers. JQueryUI is just a bunch of front-end tools which use JQuery.

To answer your question of where you can find other frameworks/libraries, Google. *Should you*? No need. They all sit on top of Javascript and do basically the same thing. Learn JQuery until you feel you are very competent and then you can make an informed decision as to whether you would like to use an alternative that has a more appealing syntax or a feature JQuery lacks. OR You code the new features and submit them as [plugins](http://plugins.jquery.com/).

Comment: `+1` for the `just a cool thing` bit lol

Answer (score 1):

[RaphaelJS](http://raphaeljs.com/) is a great library for creating vector graphics, using SVG (or VML on Internet Explorer). See the demos on the website.

Answer (score 1):

[Scriptaculous](http://script.aculo.us/) allows to create animations. Latest versions make use of the browser's hardware acceleration capabilities.

Answer (score 0):

[underscore.js](http://documentcloud.github.com/underscore/) brings some functional programming support.